# Triple Integral in Spherical coordinates $(d \rho, d \theta, d \phi) $

Tags: integration

Consider $z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2=1 $, hemisphere and cylinder respectively. Setup the triple integral in spherical coordinates (in the order $d\rho$ $d\theta$ $d\phi$) that will give the volume inside the intersection of the two solids.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Start by making a figure. Then note that from the first equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2^2$, so you have a limit for radius.

Comment: it's a volume of a cylinder plus volume of a spherical cap, split it into two integrals.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP did not react on the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use spherical co-ordinates:

$$x = \rho cos \theta cos \phi$$
$$y = \rho sin \theta cos \phi$$
$$z = \rho sin \phi$$

We have $\rho = 2$ for the spherical cap.  Also we have for the cylinder

$$\rho cos \phi = 2sin \theta$$

Solving these two equation we have

$$\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$$

Hence the volume integral should be

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\phi=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta}\int_{\rho=0}^{\frac{2sin\theta}{cos\phi}} \rho^2 cos\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta = \frac{8}{9}$$

The above answer is for the first octant.  For the whole spherical cap, the volume should be doubled.